# Getting values from the lists in python

Tags: python

I am having an input like the following type,

```
[[ 34535.54  23514.54  43213.73 ]
[ 249.01976173  132.7836   26.05499407]
[  87.26696285  107.90388887  148.68014509]]
```

I need to get the values from first,second and third rows separately 
like

```
a1=34535.54,  a2=23514.54, a3= 43213.73 
b1=249.01976173  ,b2=132.7836   ,b3=26.05499407
c1=87.26696285  ,c2=107.90388887  ,c3=148.68014509
```

How should i display the values in python?

Comment: Your input is quite not possible. Is it strings in your bracket ? Like `[" 34535.54  23514.54  43213.73"]`

Comment: Your input is missing commas.

Comment: No its not string

Comment: Do you really need variables called `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, etc.?  You should just get each "row" as a list so you could do `a[0]`, `a[1]` and so on.  Or better yet, just use the list as-is as a 2-D array: `yourList[0][0]`.

Comment: Ya.I need variables a1,a2,a3 so that i need to give these inputs to other functions

Comment: @Joe: You don't *need* them as variables for that purpose.  What's wrong with doing `func(yourList[2][1])`?

Answer (score 1):

You can break up lists in python like so:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
```

This can be extended to nested lists as well.

Answer (score 1):

In python lists are represented using commas so your input should include the commas:

```
mylist = [[34535.54, 23514.54, 43213.73],
    [249.01976173, 132.7836, 26.05499407],
    [87.26696285, 107.90388887, 148.68014509]]
```

then to acess the values in the list you use brackets

```
a1= mylis[0][0]
a2= mylis[0][1] 
a3= mylis[0][2] 

b1= mylis[1][0]  
b2= mylis[1][1]   
b3= mylis[1][2]

c1= mylis[2][0]  
c2= mylis[2][1]  
c3= mylis[2][2]
```

A more pythonic way of doing this is as, Bill mentioned:

```
[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3] = mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are some wrongs with this question:

1. It's been said many times, StackOverflow is not meant for others to write your code for you, but to help you improve your own. You have not shown us your own attempt at fixing your problem.
2. The input you show seems to contain 3 lists within 1 list, but the syntax is wrong as some have already noticed in the comments on your question.
3. Your question is not clear. Do you want 'a1' etc to be new, separate variables or just plain strings?

But, I'll write a quick reply anyways to help out.

If you want strings, try something like:

```
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
yourvariable = [[34535.54,  23514.54,  43213.73],[249.01976173,  132.7836,   26.05499407],[  87.26696285,  107.90388887,  148.68014509]]

string_result_list = []
for i in range(len(yourvariable)):
    for x in range(len(yourvariable[i])):
        y = i + 1
        string_result = str(alphabet[i]) + str(y) + '=' + str(yourvariable[i][x])
        string_result_list.append(string_result)

print(string_result_list[0])
```

If you really want all different variable, think hard if you would not rather want a list or dictionary and if not: good luck on writing the necessary code.